# JQuery news Ticker is not working in my webpage.

Tags: javascript, jquery, nivo-slider, news-ticker

[image: enter image description he[![enter image description here]re][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luC5g.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luC5g.png)

Please look at the news ticker area. Actually the jQuery link is not working. My slider is currently running under this jquery version

```
    <script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
```

But my news ticker is not working and it is visible in my given image.  On the other hand news ticker says "you will need to include jQuery (1.4.2 or above) to make all this work, I recommend using Google's Ajax Libraries API for the very latest version."
So according to their instruction when I used google API that means

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Nothing is happed and also stopped working my slider. 
Please give me a suggestion How can I done it properly that means which way the news ticker and my nivo slider will work properly .
Thank You.

Comment: Can you please provide us link of your webpage?

Comment: It is not hosted. I can provide you screenshot which you have needed.
But when I used this link news ticker worked properly but slider was not working. 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>